# Restricting folder access by role in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-5

I've been searching and searching but cannot get a straight forward answer to this. (Most of the answers I do find are outdated.)

It looks like I can restrict access to a razor page using the `Authorize` attribute on my page class.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

But, using the current version of Razor Pages, how can I restrict an entire folder or *Area*?

Comment: Did you mean that you have many Razor Pages in a folder and you wanna add role-based-authentication for all these pages and it's better to add authorizing on the folder sir?

Comment: Can [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#require-authorization-to-access-a-page) help you? I mean `AuthorizeFolder` and `AuthorizeAreaPage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's frustrating that this stuff appears to change with every release. This makes it hard to know if you're looking at the right documentation.

But this appears to be approach needed with the latest version, and it works for me.

**ConfigureServices()**

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // Create policies
    options.AddPolicy("Staff", p => p.RequireRole(Role.Staff));
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", p => p.RequireRole(Role.Admin));
});

// Set authorizations
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    // Requires staff role for all pages (not including areas)
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/", "Staff");

    // Set authorization for areas (looks like no way to do all areas at once)
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Admin", "/", "Admin");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Leasing", "/", "Staff");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Repair", "/", "Staff");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Storage", "/", "Staff");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Transloading", "/", "Staff");

    // Anonymous pages
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Index");
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Error");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Authorize folder by policy name

```cs
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(ops =>
    {
        ops.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("MyFolder", "RequireAdmins");
    });
```

Add role based policy

```cs
services.Authorization(ops =>
{
    ops.AddPolicy("RequireAdmins", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admins"));
});
```

Comment: It's frustrating as this stuff seems to change with every minor version. That's why I have trouble finding the right documentation. My existing code doesn't call `AddRazorPages()`. And with .NET 5, `IServiceCollection` has no `Authorization()` method. Ugh!